# Set up ASP.NET Core Identity as a service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Im very young in MVC apps

i would like to create a webservice providing an Identity to an external MVC app.

Benefits of exposing ASP.NET Core Identity as a service:

- The actual app code is much simpler and decoupled from its identity concerns
- Support for established authentication standards and patterns simplifies security concerns and builds trust
- The identity service can live in a separate process
- Reuse user identities across multiple apps

Is that possible ? Any ideas I can do that ?

Comment: I think you're looking for https://identityserver.io/

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.

This is how we do it.

We use IdentityServer4 to generate JWT tokens to clients. We have created a simple MVC project that has the followng simple startup file that can give you an idea.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(".", "cert", "token-cert.pfx"), "cert-password"))
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddClientStore<CustomClientStore>();

        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        // a data service to fetch user data from database
        services.AddTransient<IUserDataMapper>(s => new UserDataMapper(connectionString));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("ACME Auth Token API v1.0");
        });
    }
```

You can find a detailed explanation of IdentityServer4 at https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#defining-the-api